# Eclipse Luna content assist not working when certain classes present

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

When importing certain classes into the java file I'm currently in, the content assist just stops working. No proposals, **at all**. I cannot provide an SSCCE for confidentiality and question quality reasons. Also, this isn't reproducible in a small project.

**Didn't work**:

- Restore Defaults in CA preferences
- Clean/Refresh Eclipse & projects
- Update to SR1
- Renaming the classes

**Facts**:

- No error message / No error log in the `.metadata` folder
- <kbd>F3</kbd> does not work, neither does <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHITFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
- The classes are imported from an EJB project, into an RCP plugin project. So basically the plugin uses a compiled version of those classes, which has to be built (with Ant) each time when a modification occurs
- I mentioned "certain classes", because some work and other don't - while they're all in the same package!

I'm pretty convinced that this is an Eclipse bug.

Occurs on Eclipse Luna 4.4 and 4.4.1 - I did not encounter this on Kepler.

Comment: There may be a error in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Comment: @greg-449 There isn't. It just says `No completions available` in the Eclipse status line.

Comment: try starting eclipse from terminal or command prompt. This will help you see the stacktrace

Comment: @SairamKrish Nothing in the console, no stacktrace. What now. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an eclipse .metadata folder issue, I would try closing eclipse, blow away this folder, open eclipse and re-import your projects.